# Error: fsEvents is not a function (using Jest and create-react-app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I keep getting an error "fsEvents is not a function" when I run npm test

Fragment in package.json

```
"test": "react-scripts test"
```

Error upon running npm test

```
TypeError: fsevents is not a function
    at new FSEventsWatcher (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/FSEventsWatcher.js:162:20)
    at createWatcher (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:1052:23)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at HasteMap._watch (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:1230:44)
    at node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:517:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:193:24)
    at _next (node_modules/jest-runtime/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:213:9)
```

React scripts version: 3.0.1 (also tried 3.4.0)
Node version: v12.16.1
npm version: 4.6.1

I have tried changing the version of Node (downgrading, upgrading to latest) - doesn't work, also downgraded npm to 4.x per another post's recommendation - doesn't work.
Also tried installing the latest version of Chokidar (which I don't otherwise require as a dependency in the project).

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with react script version 3.3.0. None of the standard stuff worked including attempt to downgrade fsevents to earlier version/s. Finally executed `npm audit fix --force` to audit and fix possible security issue which fixed the above problem.

As `npm audit fix --force` may make modifications to your dependency chain, please execute and test on a seperate branch

[More info on npm-audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit)

Hope this helps